# Ajuda com comparação de datas em Java Script

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Preciso comparar data final de um contrato de serviço para colocar em um relatório que vai ter 4 tipos de status:

```
1- contrato em vigor (Verde)
2- contrato próximo ao vencimento (Amarelo)
3- contrato vencido (Vermelho)
4- contrato com prazo indeterminado (Azul)
```

Estou recendo 2 valores pelo usuário, `dt_inicio` e `dt_final`, preciso que da `dt_final` seja comparada com a `(new Date) dt_atual` ou seja, 
"Se a dt_final for >= dt_atual então o contrato está vencido." | "Se a dt_final for < dt_atual então preciso que o resultado dessa data seja transformado em meses para conseguir comparar, exemplo dt_final 27/10/2018 < dt_atual 27/06/2018 = 4 meses que vai adiciona esse valor na variável dt_vigor.

```
Se dt_vigor  =< 4(meses) então adiciona valor em (próximo_vencimento);
se dt_vigor > 4(meses) então adiciona valor em (vencimento_ok)
se não (sem_vencimento);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhar com datas em javascript é mais fácil utilizando o [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

O `moment` é bem [documentado](http://momentjs.com/docs/) e possui vários exemplos de uso.

Segue exemplo da comparação de data atual com outra(`dt_vigor`);

```js
var dt_vigor = moment("01/05/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY"); 
if(dt_vigor <= moment().subtract(4, 'month')){ 
   alert('dt_vigor tem 04 meses ou mais.'); 
   //adiciona valor em (próximo_vencimento); 
   }else{ 
   alert('dt_vigor tem menos de 04 meses.'); 
   //adiciona valor em (vencimento_ok) 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Espero ter ajudado!